# SqlConnection, Getting error and cannot connect to the database (occurred in System.Data.dll)

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net

I have just stared to learn C# 2 Weeks ago so I dont know much but right now I just want to make my first program I don't really care about the security flaw within ATM as I will fix these with time when I know a better solution.

So I got this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: A severe internal connection error has occurred.
```

And I have been sitting with this error for 2 days now modifying my code and searching the internet for solutions with no luck. So I turn here as I see there are some experts here.

Code with error:

```
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("server=SERVERIP,3306;Integrated Security=True;database=data;uid=USER;password=PASS"))
        {
            con.Open(); //ERROR HERE

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into info(Datum,Timmar,Rast) Values(@Datum,@Timmar,@Rast)", con))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timmar", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rast", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Sparat!");
            }
         }
```

So basically what I am trying to do with this program is so that the data that the user types into the textboxes gets saved in the database.

When I type word with full capital letters I mean that it's something else there eg. Ip and password etc.

Comment: Does not appear to be a code issue.  My guess is something external is messing with your connection, the .NET libraries, or system libraries.  Try code on a different machine.

Comment: I believe the problem is in your connection string 


    "server=SERVERIP,3306;Integrated Security=True;database=data;uid=USER;password=PASS"
It should be in the format

SERVERIP should be an IP address something like 10.100.10.22

Comment: @DanHunex, I am pretty sure that is just a sample string, plus it doesn't have to be an IP, it could be machine name as well.

Comment: Try using this `Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the wrong connection class.  You are trying to talk to a MySQL database as if it were a SQL Server database.

You need to use `MySqlConnection`, not `SqlConnection`. `MySqlConnection` is in [MySQL Connector/NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.9.html), which can also be installed via [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySql.Data/).

Your code should look like the following instead.

```
    using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server=SERVERIP;port=3306;database=data;uid=USER;password=PASS"))
    {
        con.Open(); // Hopefully no error here any more

        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into info(Datum,Timmar,Rast) Values(@Datum,@Timmar,@Rast)", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Datum", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Timmar", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rast", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("Sparat!");
        }
     }
```

Comment: Wow omg I cant believe it works I have tried to fix this for so long and I used the wrong connection class! I cant thank you enough! For people with this problem this is the solution, just make sure to add "port=3306" too or whatever your mysql port is

Answer (score 0):

You have `Integrated Security=true` AND `uid=USER;password=PASS`

If you are providing username and password you shouldn't have `Integrated Security=true`

Comment: I did edit the line to                      "server=SERVERIP,3306;database=data;uid=USER;password=PASS" but unfortunally doesn't work neither